# How to trap for "cannot establish secure connection"

Tags: asp.net, ssl, http-headers, tls1.2

I have a website where some people using older computers or browsers can't establish a connection to our secure portions of the site.

What I want to do is capture the connection error and re-route them to a screen explaining why this is happening and referring them to some resources that might help.

In pretty much every instance we've run into the browser/OS combination is not TLS 1.1 and/or 1.2 compatible, so they're getting denied by the server.

Is there a specific HTTP response code I should be trapping for?  I thought it might be 502, but that doesn't seem to be catching it.

Or does it not even get to that point?

When we see this with Safari, pre-version 7 the message is something like:

> Safari cannot establish secure connection

If HTTP error codes is not the way to go, is there a good way to trap for this?  I'm using asp.net to manage our web site.

EDIT: Anyone know the sequence the server and browser go through in this situation?  Figuring where to intervene/trap is half the battle for me, I think.  This edit was more to bump, since I have no responses yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is managed by your web server, not ASP.NET, so there is no way you can intercept the TLS connection failure inside your ASP.NET code.

What you could do is to have a proxy in front of your website that will accept incoming connections with TLS < 1.2 and respond to the client with error page immediately. It will pass all acceptable connections with proper version of TLS to the web server.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I don't know, not an expert, but unlikely.